# hyperref and xr-hyper break memoir's \titleref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, memoir, xr

I have one document that has `hyperref` loaded, and works fine.

I have a second document that I am using `xr-hyper` to reference the first. If I remove `hyperref` from the first document, the `\titleref{}` (from `memoir`) command works as expected. If I use `hyperref` I get "See Chapter 1" instead of "See Chapter Example".

Here are the two files that show this behavior:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}\label{chap:example}

Examples
\end{document}
```

Call that one `example.tex`, run `pdflatex` on it, and then the second file references it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\externaldocument{example}
\begin{document}
See Chapter~\ref{chap:example} on page~\pageref{chap:example} which is called~\titleref{chap:example}.
\end{document}
```

Compile the second file and the issue will appear. Remove or comment out `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the first file and rerun both `pdflatex` commands and the `\titleref` command will work, but the first document won't have any hyperreferences.

I suspect that the problem is that the `example.aux` file has

```
\newlabel{chap:example}{{\M@TitleReference {1}{Example}}{1}}
```

in the working case, and

```
\newlabel{chap:example}{{1}{1}{Example}{chapter.1}{}}
```

in the case that doesn't work. I suppose I can compile my first file without `hyperref` and then the second file, and then turn `hyperref` on again and recompile the first file.

Comment: Even though you haven't asked a specific *question*, I assume you want to find a work-around for this broken behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make this work, rely solely on [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) to manage the titles in the target/external document. Why? Because it wasn't compiled under the [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class, and therefore has no reference of the `\titleref` requirements. Use `\nameref` instead.

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{xr-hyper,hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xr-hyper,hyperref}
\externaldocument{example}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Some chapter}\label{chap:current}
See Chapter~\ref{chap:example} on page~\pageref{chap:example} which is called~\nameref{chap:example}.

See Chapter~\ref{chap:current} on page~\pageref{chap:current} which is called~\titleref{chap:current}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is working, but now I get another (perhaps related) issue. The references to the external document don't work with `memoir \NumToName`: `Chapter~\NumToName{\ref{chap:example}}` errors out with Missing number. Should I create a new question?

Comment: @bombcar: It would think so, since it's complete different in nature from this one. It may be helpful to [reference this question in the follow-up](http://goo.gl/vWjuk).

Answer (score 5):

Package `zref-xref` can be used instead of `xr-hyper`, even if the `zref` labels are not used, because `\zexternaldocument` also can import and export from LaTeX labels with or without `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zxrsetup{
  tozreflabel=false,
  toltxlabel=true,  
}
\zexternaldocument*{example}

\begin{document}
See Chapter~\ref{chap:example} on page~\pageref{chap:example} which is
called~\titleref{chap:example}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- Package `nameref` changes the internal label format. It is loaded by package `hyperref` via `\AtBeginDocument` at a late time. However `\zexternaldocument` should know it, thus the example ensures that `nameref` is loaded before.

Comment: What are the advantages of `zref-xr` as opposed to simple `xr`?

Comment: @bombcar: Better support of the various combinations of packages (with/without `hyperref`, `nameref`, `titleref`, ...). It should be a superset of `xr` and `xr-hyper`.