# Memoir's \NumToName doesn't work with cross-referenced items

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, memoir, xr

I got external references to work with `memoir` and `hyperref` here: [hyperref and xr-hyper break memoir's \titleref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163902/hyperref-and-xr-hyper-break-memoirs-titleref), but references to external documents don't work with `memoir \NumToName`: `Chapter~\NumToName{\ref{chap:example}}` errors out with `Missing number`.

Here are the two files that show this behavior:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}\label{chap:example}

Examples
\end{document}
```

Call that one `example.tex`, run `pdflatex` on it, and then the second file references it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\externaldocument{example}
\begin{document}
See Chapter~\NumToName{\ref{chap:example}}.
\end{document}
```

Compile the second file and the issue will appear.

Here's the error message I get:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.7     See Chapter~\NumToName{\ref{chap:example}}
```

How to I get a NumToName reference to an external document?

Comment: it has to be a number, `\ref` generally isn't (not on the `TeX` level), see Karls solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this issue by loading the package `refcount` and substituting `\ref` with `\getrefnumber`.

To creat the link you can use the command `\hyperref` from the `hyperref` package.

In other words, rewrite your latter file as

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}

\externaldocument{example}
\begin{document}
See Chapter~\hyperref[chap:example]{\NumToName{\getrefnumber{chap:example}}}.
\end{document}
```

and you will get the expected output:

[image]

Comment: Embarrassingly I got really close to this solution but forgot to wrap `\getrefnumber` itself in `{}`