# \pageref not working properly in main document with subfiles package and xr package

Tags: cross-referencing, subfiles, xr

I have a main file setup with the `subfiles` package and the `xr` package. I am trying to make the `\pageref` command work properly for cross-references in the main file, but the page number it displays in the main file is not correct, although it *is* correct in the subfile. My setup in the `main.tex` is as follows:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,final]{memoir}
 \usepackage{kpfonts}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{subfiles}
 %
 \providecommand{\main}{.}
 %
 \usepackage{xr}
    \externaldocument[ch1-]{\main/chap/chapter1/ch1}
    \externaldocument[ch2-]{\main/chap/chapter2/ch2}
%
\begin{document}
%... some other subfiles
\subfile{chap/chapter1/ch1.tex}
\subfile{chap/chapter2/ch2.tex}
\end{document}
```

Now in the file `ch1.tex` I have the following setup:

```
\providecommand{\main}{../../}
\documentclass[../../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
Some text.... \newpage
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{picture}
    \caption{Some picture}
    \label{fig:picture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And then in the file `ch2.tex` I have the following:

```
\providecommand{\main}{../../}
\documentclass[../../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{2}
As shown in figure~\ref{ch1-fig:picture} on page~\pageref{ch1-fig:picture} the labelling works.
\end{document}
```

Now, when I compile the subfiles `ch1.tex` and `ch2.tex`, the page numbering associated with `\pageref{ch1-fig:picture}` gives the correct page in `ch2.tex`, which is page 2 in the subfile `ch1.tex`, but when I compile the main file the page-numbering doesn't get updated for some reason, since it should be on page 4 of the main file. I really can't figure out why the main file behaves this way, since the subfiles are able to update accordingly, if the picture gets moved to a different page in the subfile. My setup is partly inspired by the constructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235973/subfiles-and-referencing?rq=1) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files). Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
It seems like the references to the labels do not work properly either, since in the maindocument, the labels do get updated to the correct numbers, but when trying to make a reference to them later or before, the numbers in the references are wrong.

Comment: As far as I see, the `subfiles` package does not take care about the labels, which is totally different with a `\include` approach

Comment: Is there any kind of workaround for it? Since I don't want to change all my file setup just for getting the pageref command to work.

Comment: I know of none, but this does not mean there's none!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a slight workaround for the problem by simply letting all the labels refer to the main document, i.e. essentially commenting out the `\externaldocument[ch1-]{\main/chap/chapter1/ch1}`parts etc but keeping an `\externaldocument[t-]{\main/main}` present, so that the subfiles can find the correct labels in the main document. This makes it so that when cross-referencing things between the subfiles, I just have to make sure the labels are present in the main document by compiling the main document a few times.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that hyperref works in combination with section and subsection. That means if you omit section or subsection, then you are not likely to go to another page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pdftex}

\begin{document}

%\section{something}
whatever insteresting

something \hyperref[a]{hyperref link}

\newpage
%\section{something}
whatever boring

something else \label{a} 

\end{document}
```

Like if you don't comment out the section, then it works fine

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zxrsetup{
  tozreflabel=false,
  toltxlabel=true,  
}
\zexternaldocument*{example}
```

istead of

```
 \usepackage{xr}
    \externaldocument[ch1-]{\main/chap/chapter1/ch1}
    \externaldocument[ch2-]{\main/chap/chapter2/ch2}
```

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163953/110064