# tcolorbox: \newtcbtheorem with \zref reference system for multivolume book

Tags: tcolorbox, zref

I would like to use nice package `tcolorbox` for frames together with modern reference system `zref`.

My `\newtcbtheorem` looks like:

```
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter]{mathexam}{MyExample}{%
   % colback=purple!5,
   % colframe=blue!100!,
   fonttitle=\itshape,        % \bfseries,
   fontupper=\small,
   fontlower=\footnotesize,
   enforce breakable,         % breakable,
   compress page,
   enhanced,
   arc=1pt, left=0pt,right=0pt
}{mai}
```

but it produce:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `mai:exam038' on page 12 undefined on input line 262.
```

although I did the translation several times.Is it even possible to use both libraries together?

My motivation to use `zref`package is to create multivolume book with my school notes from different subjects. Package `zref-xref` can be used instead of `xr-hyper`as it is shown in the [Heiko Oberdiek's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163902/hyperref-and-xr-hyper-break-memoirs-titleref).

My complete MNWE is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
  \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter]{mathexam}{Problem}{%
    % colback=purple!5,
    % colframe=blue!100!,
      fonttitle=\itshape,        % \bfseries,
      fontupper=\small,
      fontlower=\footnotesize,
      enforce breakable,         % breakable,
      compress page,
      enhanced,
      arc=1pt, left=0pt,right=0pt
  }{mai}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[user, counter]{zref}
%  \usepackage{zref-xr}
%  \zexternaldocument*{example}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Algebra}\zlabel{chap:math1}
    This is a test for math.
    \begin{equation}
      E=mc^2 \zlabel{eq:1}
    \end{equation}
    This is a second test for math.
    \begin{equation}
      r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \zlabel{eq:2}
    \end{equation}
    In the document A there is chapter \nameref{chap:math1} see the eqation \zref{eq:2}. 

  Solve the problem shown in example \zref{exam038}

  \section{Bunch of examples}
    Let's solve following problems
    \begin{mathexam}{Gauss method}{exam038}
      \(3x + 4y = 5\)
    \end{mathexam}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should know that one need a complete example to test.

Answer (score 1):

tcolorbox doesn't have support for zref. You could make a feature request, or redefine \label so that issues \zlabel too, or patch a tcolorbox command. nameref can be replaced the titleref module.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
  \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=chapter]{mathexam}{Problem}{%
    % colback=purple!5,
    % colframe=blue!100!,
      fonttitle=\itshape,        % \bfseries,
      fontupper=\small,
      fontlower=\footnotesize,
      enforce breakable,         % breakable,
      compress page,
      enhanced,
      arc=1pt, left=0pt,right=0pt,
  }{mai}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[user, counter,titleref]{zref}
%  \usepackage{zref-xr}
%  \zexternaldocument*{example}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd\tcb@set@label{\zlabel{#1}}{}{\fail}
% if nameref is loaded, else patch \tcb@gettitle
\pretocmd\NR@gettitle{\zref@titleref@setcurrent{#1}}{}{\fail}
%\pretocmd\tcb@gettitle{\zref@titleref@setcurrent{#1}}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

  \chapter{Algebra}\zlabel{chap:math1}
    This is a test for math.
    \begin{equation}
      E=mc^2 \zlabel{eq:1}
    \end{equation}
    This is a second test for math.
    \begin{equation}
      r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \zlabel{eq:2}
    \end{equation}
    In the document A there is chapter \ztitleref{chap:math1} see the equation \zref{eq:2}.

  Solve the problem shown in example \zref{mai:exam038}

  \section{Bunch of examples}
    Let's solve following problems
    \begin{mathexam}{Gauss method}{exam038}
      \(3x + 4y = 5\)
    \end{mathexam}
    
    \ztitleref{mai:exam038}
\end{document}
```